# Linking Armadillo Library in C++ Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, homebrew, armadillo

I am new to Mac and also Armadillo. Here's what I've done to use C++ with Armadillo.

- Downloaded and installed Xcode
- Downloaded and installed Homebrew
- In terminal typed "brew install armadillo"

Aside from that it's basically factory settings on the Mac.

Downloading armadillo seemed to work in brew, but I'm not really sure what to do next, because my code (shown below) still isn't compiling. It still says armadillo can't be found.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   mat A;
   A << 1 << 2 << endr << 3 << 4 endr;
   cout << A << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I know there's probably something simple I'm missing but I'm pretty new to all of it so I'd appreciate advice, thanks.

Comment: you just need to put armadillo path to  your project configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out after searching around. The fact that `/usr/bin/` was hidden was really confusing me, but you can just `cd` there from the Terminal, I guess. Then Armadillo was at the path `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/4.600.2/include`, which I copied into `Search Paths` -> `Header Search Paths` in Xcode.

Comment: You can also install Armadillo using CMake instead of going through Homebrew. See `README.txt` that comes with the official Armadillo .tar.gz [package](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html). The CMake based installation will put Armadillo headers into `/usr/include/`.  This path should be searched by Xcode by default.

Answer (score 3):

I used the default cmake options, so my armadillo.h .dylib ended up 
in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib, respectfully.

1) Add the paths containing armadillo.h and the armadillo.5.20.2.dylib to Header Search Paths, and Library Search Paths.

[Search Path Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTEfn.png)

The search dialog box is useful in locating the aforementioned project parameters.

2) Add the dylab as a target dependency

[Link Binary With Libraries Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnClI.png)

Click '+' ->  Add Other -> ⌘  Shift G -> /usr/local

Then select /usr/local/lib/armadillo.5.20.2.dylib

In restrospect it is probably better to run cmake with an alternate install location such as:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt
```

In which case the `⌘  Shift G`  step is unnecessary, and one can probably see the /opt directory from Finder by typing `sudo SetFile  -a  v  /opt`